# Rewrite DB::raw() query to simple DB::table()

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have a `DB::raw()` query in Laravel 5.3.

One of `WHERE` clauses is `AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, profiles.dob, CURDATE()) >= '$min_age'`. Here I'm checking if user's year of birth is greater or equal to a certain number (user age).

How can I rewrite this clause using `DB::table()` without `DB::raw()`, if possible?

```
DB::select(
            DB::raw(
                "SELECT profiles.dob, profiles.city, profiles.id, users.username, photos.photo "
                . "FROM profiles INNER JOIN users ON profiles.id = users.id "
                    . "LEFT JOIN photos ON profiles.id = photos.profile_id "
                . "WHERE users.active = 1 "
                    . "AND profiles.income >= '$seekingIncome' "
                    . "AND profiles.religion IN ('$seekingReligion') "
                    . "AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, profiles.dob, CURDATE()) >= '$min_age' "
                    . "AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, profiles.dob, CURDATE()) <= '$max_age' "
                . "GROUP BY profiles.id"
        ));
```

This is simplified version...

Comment: can you update your question, Add complete query which you want to convert into `DB::table` standards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your query, this should be work:

```
DB::table('profiles')
->select('profiles.dob', 'profiles.city', 'profiles.id', 'users.username', 'photos.photo')
->join('users','profiles.id','=','users.id')
->leftJoin('photos'.'profiles.id','=','photos.profile_id')
->where('users.active',1)
->where('profiles.income','>=',$seekingIncome)
->whereIn('profiles.religion', $seekingReligion)
->whereRaw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, profiles.dob, CURDATE()) >= "?"',[$min_age])
->whereRaw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, profiles.dob, CURDATE()) <= "?"',[$max_age])
->groupBy('profiles.id')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I needed.